# Output strings of an array into a JTextArea in java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, file, jtextarea

Hi I have made a program that reads a text file containing words and adds it to an array. I now need the words to display in the JTextArea I have created but Im not sure how to. The text file contains one word per line, thats how I want the JTextArea to also display them.

Here is the code so far. The JTextArea I have is called textArea (its created in another method)

```
    public static void file() {

    List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();

    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/WordFile.txt"));
        String word;

        while ((word = br.readLine()) != null) {
            wordList.add(word);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    String[] words = new String[wordList.size()];
    wordList.toArray(words);
}
```

Comment: You've described a problem and how you can't do it, but have so far not asked a question (let alone a specific, answerable question).  Do you have a question?

Comment: *"..file contains one word per line, thats how I want .. to also display them."*  Sounds like a list of items.  In that case, look to a `JList` over a `JTextArea`.

Comment: Wow - I need help on displaying the contents of the array in the JTextArea. Also I need to use JTextArea

Comment: @jj007: Although I answered using `JTextArea` but @Andrew is right `JList` will be a better option.

Comment: That is a statement, not a question.  Even if it were a question, it is really too broad an area to fit be a good fit at SO.

Comment: hmmm If I used JList, how would I add the contents? Is there an example code of adding contents of an array to a JList?

Comment: Have you looked for the JList tutorial? It's all there, yours for the learning with only small effort on your part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a JTextArea object.

As, @Andrew suggested the correct function is [JTextArea.append(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29)

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

for(String W: Words)
  textArea.append(W);
```

[JTextArea tutorial Java Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

Comment: I tried that and it only shows the last word in the array. I want it to display the whole array

Comment: You might wan't to elaborate on "objects" when I was learning this, I had no idea how an object could help let alone how to implement it.

Comment: @Russell: thats why i have added the official tutorial link.

Comment: To get it to display all words, change it into an array (look on the web how) and use a for() loop to place all the words in to the TextField.

Comment: I have changed it into an array

Comment: @RanRag  ITYM [`JTextArea.append(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: what do you mean by no luck.? what is your `textarea` displaying.

Comment: Firstly I tried for(String W: Words)
                textArea.append(W); but it doesnt load anything

Comment: I put it at the end of the method

Comment: Have a a look at this small example i created for your http://pastebin.com/TVfcSPxQ. Try running this on your system.

Comment: Thanks! Can that same technique apply for an array of strings using a text file?

Comment: ofcourse save your text file into an array of strings. and use a for loop like this `for(String W: Words)
  textArea.append(W);`

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) tutorial to see how to use TextAreas. Basically, want you want to do is to iterate over the array and print it's contents through the Event Dispatcher Thread (the thread which takes care of the GUI). This is usually done through the use of the [SwingUtils.invokeLater()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)